# Detection of theme being used

Tags: php, themes

OK, this may be a dumb question. Is it possible, using PHP, to detect which theme has been set for use by Wordpress ? If so, how's it done ?

Thanks.

Comment: The bigger question here is why you would need this information. I have the suspicion that your need to get the current theme may be due to some other, possibly non-standard, approach that could probably be done a lot easier the "WordPress way". Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 6):

If you only need the current theme name, you can use [get_current_theme()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_theme).

Answer (score 3):

This snippet will get the current theme info for you.

```
$theme_data = wp_get_theme();
echo $theme_data->Name;
```

See [`wp_get_theme`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_theme) for more information.